# Closure not returning anything

Tags: javascript

I am reading a book and there is an example of closure here

```
function newFunc(fn) {
    fn();
}

function foo() {
    var a = 2;

    function innerFunc() {
        console.log(a); // 2
    }

    newFunc(innerFunc);
}
```

But it does not return 2. **It shows blank is console**. why is that?

Comment: do you call `foo()`?

Comment: works in my console, if you call foo()

Comment: you need to return inner function, not call.

Comment: @user1623481: He does not call `innerFunc` anywhere. He passes it around as an argument. Which is totally fine.

Comment: that doesn't make this closure. he is just calling functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to invoke `foo` function which will in turn call the `newFunc` with `innerFunc` as parameter.

```js
function newFunc(fn) {
  fn();
}

function foo() {
  var a = 2;

  function innerFunc() {
    console.log(a); // 2
  }

  newFunc(innerFunc);
}

foo(); // Invoke foo function
```

Comment: this is not closure Marc!

Comment: @user1623481: Of course it is. What else would it be?

Comment: this is closure: `function foo() {
  var a = 2;

  return function innerFunc() {
    console.log(a); // 2
  };

  
}

 var x = new foo();
     x()
`